# 他の誰もコミットしない一人開発で、後から履歴を振り返りたいだけの場合は、「GitHub」のどこへ PUSH すればよいですか？

Tags: git, github

Git BASH 経由で GitHub へ PUSH する際、他の誰もコミットしない一人開発で、後から履歴を振り返りたいだけの場合は、「GitHub」のどこへ PUSH すればよいですか？

本体とブランチがあるのではなく、デフォルトブランチ(「Default branch」＝「main」)とそれ以外のブランチがあるという感じですか？
「git push -u origin」みたいなことは(本体がないので)できない？

ブランチを切らない、とはどういう意味ですか？
デフォルトブランチ(「Default branch」＝「main」)だけで開発を進めていくということですか？

Comment: 「どこへ push すれば」とブランチの話は別じゃないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub を利用するのは、主に複数ユーザーでコードを共有する場合ですが、自分自身が複数のPCを利用する場合も含まれます。

単純に履歴を管理したいだけであれば、GitHub に push せずとも、ローカルで Git を利用するだけで事足ります。

---

GitHub を利用した場合も、コラボレータとして他のユーザを追加しない限りは、自分自身しか直接コミットを更新することはできません。ただし、デフォルトではパブリック (公開) に設定されるので、見られたらコードが含まれるような場合にはプライベートに設定するといった運用も考えられます。